# Pre-Order product Magento

Tags: magento

Is there a way to add a custom satus in the order for products that has set Pre-Order option ?

I have figured out the basic steps to add the product to be pre-ordered but my question is if can i add also a rule to set a custom Status in the Order Status from Pending to Pending - Preorder-Date.

Created an attribute name `preorder` with Yes/No.

File edited:

/app/design/frontend/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
if($_product->getPreorder()){
    $buttonTitle = $this->__('Pre-Order'); 
}else{
    $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); 
}
```

Now in checkout if items has `getPreorder` set to Yes will add a custom note with 'This product is in Pre-Order mode'.

Now what model/controller i need to edit to set a custom status if `getPreorder` is set to Yes.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new Status without code

```
Admin Panel > System > Order Statuses
```

The right Model for that is:

```
$orderStatusModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')->getCollection();
print_r( $orderStatusModel->getData() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your product as backorder product from;

```
Admin Panel > Catalog > Manage Products > Inventory > Backorders
```

Then you can check your product is in backorder;

```
$_stockitem =  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$backorder = $_stockitem->getBackorders();

if($backorder) {
    echo "Product is in backorder";
} else {
    echo "Not";
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and format your code example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting